# Thread behaviour different when device is connected to pc as compare to when its not - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

Please help me understand why I am seeing the behavior that I am.
I have a test android application, on a click of a button it creates a new thread, which is supposed to work in background and creates another thread which draws a clock like dial. I am trying to do something when device screen is off.
Now when my device is connected to my pc(eclipse) I can see debugging statements, I start the thread and press the power button once to turn off the screen, the app behaves as I intend to and after the timer expires(thread keeps running when screen goes dark) the code turns on the screen and then does some other stuff.
However my problem is when device is not connected to the pc (eclipse) I do the same thing but it seems like thread is paused and only will resume again when screen is on...
Is this normal?
Why thread would no pause while device is connected and will do when its not?
Please can some one shed some light here
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have figured out a work around to my issue just in case some one else may stumble upon this or similar problem.

What I have done is when my new thread is started, I create a partial wake lock and when process is completed it release it.

There are many code snippets and tutorials out there on how to use WakeLock for android..

Thanks for all those who reviewed the question.